# access middleware options when invoke

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm creating a custom middleware element but can't figure out how to pass on the Options object to the middleware and access them in the Invoke method.

**Config**:

```
public class MiddleConfig
{
    private readonly ICollection<string> _c;

    public MiddleConfig()
    {
        _c = new Collection<string>();
    }

    public void AddPath(string path)
    {
        _c.Add(path);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Paths => _c;
}
```

**MiddleConfig**:

```
public class Middle
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly MiddleConfig _opt = new MiddleConfig();

    public Middle(RequestDelegate next, MiddleConfig options)
    {
        _opt = options;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

**Extension**:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddLCPathControl(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MiddleConfig> options)
{
    MiddleConfig opt = new MiddleConfig();
    options.Invoke(opt);

    return services.AddScoped<Middle>();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what problem you have. You're passing the options via the constructor and storing it in an instance variable, so you can access the variable in the `Invoke` method.

Comment: @Stijn so that's the way to do it? isn't it possible to somehow get the value in the constructor? The constructor for my little middleware takes two parameters, RequestDelegate and MiddleConfig. I can't initiate a object from Middle since I can't supply RequestDelegate

Comment: You're trying to construct an instance of `Middle` yourself? Either way, I think I understand your problem now: you're not registering `opt` in the DI container, so inside the middleware `_opt` is null (or it crashes), correct? Take a look at [the documentation and example for writing middleware](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#write-middleware), and possibly [the documentation on the Options pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1) will also be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using the wrong method to add middleware.

Changed to add the middleware to ApplicationBuilder and use UseMiddleware<>() which can't take options as I wanted.

**Extension**:

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseLCPathControl(this IApplicationBuilder services, string path)
    {
        return services.UseLCPathControl(o => o.AddPath(path));
    }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseLCPathControl(this IApplicationBuilder builder, Action<MiddleConfig> options)
    {
        MiddleConfig opt = new MiddleConfig();
        options.Invoke(opt);

        return builder.UseMiddleware<Middle>(opt);
    }
}
```

**Middle**:

```
public class Middle
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly MiddleConfig _opt = new MiddleConfig();

    public Middle(RequestDelegate next, MiddleConfig options)
    {
        _opt = options;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

**MiddleConfig**:

```
public class MiddleConfig
{
    private readonly ICollection<string> _c;

    public MiddleConfig()
    {
        _c = new Collection<string>();
    }

    public void AddPath(string path)
    {
        _c.Add(path);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Paths => _c;
}
```